# xlsx package: Array of object to json -date field value is trimmed for some rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I am facing a weird issue in xlsx while converting an array of objects to an excel

Input array

```
const  input=[{id:1,DOb:'02/23/1984'},{id:2,DOb:'02/23/1985'},{id:3,DOb:'02/23/1985'},{id:4,DOb:'02/23/1940'}]
```

In the output excel file, the DOB value is trimmed for some rows,

The above example returns the DOB value in excel is `02/23/40` for the input `02/23/1940`.

As you see the year `1940` is trimmed to `40` What I need to exact version of the input  ie `1940`.

Here is the code

```
    const workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(input)
    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new()

    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, workSheet, 'Sheet1')
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, path)
```

Comment: i tested and got it without problem. i had added `XLSX.writeFile(wb, path,{bookType: 'xlsx'})` not sure if it makes any difference

Comment: Thanks for the comment but still the same issue

Comment: also i was doing this in client side `XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'filename.xlsx',{bookType....` and i was using https://github.com/gitbrent/xlsx-js-style

Comment: Can you try adding another column to see if it affects

Comment: Sure let me try

Comment: if nothing helps here as well. you can also raise an issue on sheetjs github

Comment: Actually that input is came from another excel file which parsed using the same xlsx package in that i can see the date is trimmed